# Run vs Ran question

Tags: tense

I know this has been asked. I understand that ran is past and run is perfect past tense. However, I am still somewhat confused on what is correct in this case:

> This report section contains data for 25 units ran at X and Y conditions

or

> This report section contains data for 25 units run at X and Y conditions

Answer (score 2):

The first is wrong, the second right. I don't know enough grammar to tell you just why.

The "at X and Y conditions" is awkward. I might say "under conditions X and Y".

Comment: Agree for sure. Something to do w the phrase being a modifier of “units”

Comment: Also “conditions X and Y” is better

Answer (score 1):

The second one is correct - it implies *which were run*.

It would be possible to say *which I/we ran*, but this would be less appropriate in a technical report.